# HighCharts Export Server not rendering series marker symbols consistently

Tags: c#, highcharts

The graph exported by the export server fails to render the images from a specified URL that are to be used as the marker for each series datapoint, such as of the following example:

```
"series":[{"data":[{"y":0.06,"x":3.5815,"marker":{"symbol":"url(https://www.highcharts.com/samples/graphics/sun.png)","width":40,"height":40}}}]
```

The rendering is inconsistent in the sense that it loads at times and doesn't at others. I am assuming the highchart export server returns the graph much before the images from the URL are loaded onto it.

Alternatively, is there any other way to load images as markers onto the graph by passing such a parameter in the JSON file?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you already reported this issue here: https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server/issues/43. Until this bug is fixed, you can use the older version of the export server (using PhantomJS). At the bottom of this page: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/render-charts-serverside you will find instruction how to install and configure legacy export server. Here is the example of use:

```
phantomjs highcharts-convert.js -infile options.js -outfile chart.png
```

I tried to generate image this way and it renders without any problems, resulting in:

[image: Created with legacy export server]

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer! We had put this on temporary hold, so couldn't reply earlier. The solution however doesn't work when trying to render the graph using the phantomjsserver to which multiple calls will be made -- which we will be needing to generate multiple parallel charts

Comment: I think the best solution is to wait for the fix to be made.